# how do I get my iPhone contacts onto my new MacBook Pro, so that I can send iMessages from my computer, instead of my phone?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I just bought another MacBook Pro and I want to send and receive text messages from my mac instead of my iPhone. How do I get my MacBook Pro to sync with my iPhone as it used to on my old MacBook?

Comment: What account are you using on your iPhone for your Contacts?

Comment: just my regular contacts that I have on my Iphone; I can text the Iphone users as well as android uses from my iphone-but I want to do that from my laptop as well. I used to be able to, and now I can't.

Comment: You have to synchronize your accounts.  Under Settings→Passwords & Accounts you will see a list of Accounts (iCloud, Google, whatever).  Can you post a screen shot of that screen?  Either way, whatever account you're using there has to match on your Mac.  That way, the contacts will by synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the same iCloud device on both, and allow Messages in the cloud on both devices. On your iPhone, go to Settings > Tap your name at the top > iCloud. Make sure, both Contacts and Messages are enabled.

Then go back to iMessage on the Mac and go through the configuration there. You may need to open iMessage preferences, then go to the iMessage tab and check most of the boxes there.